# Let $n = p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2} \dots p_k^{a_k}$. Show that $d(n) = (a_1+1)(a_2+1)\dots(a_k+1)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Let $n = p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2} \dots p_k^{a_k}$. Show that $d(n) = (a_1+1)(a_2+1)\dots(a_k+1).$

How should I go about this? I tried to first show that the divisor function is multiplicative and use that result to prove the statement, but it seems that the multiplicativity depends on the result I'm actually trying to show? Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: The proof that the divisor function is multiplicative does not depend on this result. **HINT:** Given two coprime integers $n$ and $m$, write all the divisors of $n$ as rows in a table and $m$ as a column. What happens when we multiply the the pairs of divisors together?

Answer (score 0):

Any factor of $n$ is of the form $d=p_1^{\beta_1}p_2^{\beta_2}...p_k^{\beta_k}$ where  $0\le\beta_i\le a_i$. It is clear that there are $a_i+1$ choices (including $0$) for each $\beta_i$ giving us a total of $(a_1+1)(a_2+1)...(a_k+1)$ factors.

Comment: So suppose that $n = 5^2 = 25$ the divisors of $25$ are $1,5$ and $25$ itself. Then $d=p_1^{\beta_1}p_2^{\beta_2}...p_k^{\beta_k}$ would state that $d$ could be $d = 5^0 5^1 5^2 = 125$ which is clearly not a factor of $25$?

Comment: No! $p_1,p_2,...,p_k$ are **distinct** prime factors of $n$! Since $25=5^2$ has only one prime factor i.e. $5$, its divisors are $5^{\beta_1}$ where $0\le\beta_1\le2$.

Comment: I see. So in the case $5^2$ we would have only $p_1 = 5$ and $\beta_1 = 0, \beta_2 = 1, \beta_3 = 2$?

Comment: Yeah. The condition that $d=p_1^{\beta_1}...p_k^{\beta_k}$ with $0\le\beta_i\le a_i$ basically says that the exponent of each prime factor in $d$ is less than the exponent of that prime factor in $n$ so that $d$ can divide $n$.

Answer (score 0):

If $d $is a divisor of $n, $we can take any one of $0,...,a_{i} $for each $p_{i} $. Since these are all powers of primes, by uniqueness of prime factorizations each way to choose is distinct.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if $d\ \vert \ n$:

$$d = p_{1}^{b_{1}}p_{2}^{b_{2}}...p_{k}^{b_{k}}\ \ \text{where}\  0\leq b_{i}\leq a_{i}$$

Then, there are $a_{i} + 1$ (from $0$ to $a_{i}$) possible values for each $b_{i}$. Thus, $\boxed{d(n) = (a_{1} + 1)(a_{2} + 1)...(a_{k} + 1)}$